# jQuery animate expand and contract using right property

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I've got 2 boxes on a page, one expands to the right with an animation when you press a blue box. The blue box changes to a red box which should be the button for it to revert back to its original size (width) and place. (The 2nd box is supposed to stay up in the top right corner.) Once it contracts to the original size again the button should change back to blue and the process can start again so the expanding and contracting can keep happening.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//open & close 1 //open & close 2... (irrelevant code omitted here, just some extra buttons)

//minimise 1
$(".minT").click(function () {
    $('.box1').animate({right:'+=49.5%'}, "slow");
});
//change minimise to expand
$(".minT").click(function () {
$('.minT').removeClass('minT').addClass('expT');
});

//expand 1 & close 2
$(".expT").click(function () {
    $('.box2').animate(
    {width:'20px',
    height:'20px',
    right:'75px',
    top:'5px',
    bottom:'show',
    left:'90%'}, "fast", function(){
        $('.box1').animate({right:'-=49.5%'}, "slow", function(){
});});});
//change expand button to a minimise button
$(".expT").click(function () {
$('.expT').removeClass('expT').addClass('minT');
});
});
```

I don't know what I have to do for it to work... I've tried fiddling with the right value on the minimise code section but it doesn't seem to like it and just expands more and more. (I also had the expand value set to right:'1%' which put it to the same position but it wouldn't do anything when I'd click the red box.) Could it be something to do with my changing classes from expT to minT?

Here's a link to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/c7SLV/1/

Thank you for any help you can give me in advance!

Pbob

Comment: So the only problem is is just keeps expanding instead of going back to its original size?

Comment: @user1795832 yeah, it should be able to contract then be able to expand again and be interchangeable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `unbind("click")` when you remove the class. It is still performing the click event of the old class after you have removed it and added the new class. I updated the fiddle in

```
$(".expT").click(function () {
        $('.expT').removeClass('expT').unbind("click").addClass('minT').click(function(){
            $('.box1').animate({right:'+=49.5%'}, "slow");
        });
});
```

This gets `box1` to return to its original size.

Comment: nice, thank you! Although it should change back to expT class when you click on minT. http://jsfiddle.net/c7SLV/4/

Comment: Here is the new fiddle with it expanding and contracting and expanding again - http://jsfiddle.net/c7SLV/4/

Comment: I think I forgot to save the fiddle I had done. Here is a new link - http://jsfiddle.net/c7SLV/5/

Comment: ahh I see! Thank you so much, I've learnt a lot from reading that. Just one question, why do you have to put it as '.box 1 div' with the unbind & removeClass function and not just selecting .expT to remove the class from?

Thank you for being so helpful though :D

Comment: No reason. I just wrote it that way. It could be `$('.minT')` or `$('.expT')`